# JSON doesn't get email when used with facebook connect

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used Facebook connect API to retrieve user basic data from his account on facebook, i'm connecting from java appliation through servlet:

```
private void getUserMailAddressFromJsonResponse(String accessToken,
        HttpSession httpSession) {
    String email = null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        if (accessToken != null && !"".equals(accessToken)) {
            String newUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="
                    + accessToken;
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(newUrl);
            System.out.println("Get info from face --> executing request: "
                    + httpget.getURI());
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget,
                    responseHandler);
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer
                    .toJSON(responseBody);
            System.out.println("Attributes inside Json "+json.toString());
            String facebookId = json.getString("id");
            String firstName = json.getString("first_name");
            String lastName = json.getString("last_name");
            email= json.getString("email");  // not founding email

            // put user data in session
            httpSession.setAttribute("FACEBOOK_USER", firstName + ","+lastName+","+email+","+facebookId);

        } else {
            System.err.println("Token za facebook je null");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    // return email;
}
```

the exception:

```
net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["email"] not found
```

this is a method in a managed bean that forms the URL:

```
public String getFacebookUrlAuth() {
    System.out.println("Called");
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    String sessionId = session.getId();
    System.out.println("SessionId:" + sessionId);
    String appId = "3607596261352927";
    String redirectUrl = "http://localhost:8080/Gambak/index.sec";
    String returnValue = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
            + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl
            + "&scope=email,user_birthday&state=" + sessionId;
    System.out.println("return value: " + returnValue);
    return returnValue;
}
```

the strange thing is that i successfully got the email 3 days ago and it was working well, when i tried it today i got that exception!!

Comment: Do you have the [email permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/) ?

Comment: String returnValue = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
            + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl
            + "&scope=email,user_birthday&state=" + sessionId;

Answer (score 1):

" *Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty.* "

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-email